# hide element on condition using AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Using AlpineJS I have the following:

```
<div x-data="pricing()" x-init="data = { plan: 'a' }">

  <p><span x-text="calculate() + '€'"></span>per session</p>

  <select x-model="data.plan">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select>

</div>

export default function pricing() {

  return {

    data: {
      plan: "",
    },  

    calculate() {
      if (this.data.plan == "a")
        return 20;

      return 30;
    }
  }
}
```

How to hide the `span` if `calculate()` returns `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Your x-model controlled element needs to be inside your x-data container:

```
<div x-data="pricing()" x-init="data = { plan: 'a' }">
  <p><span x-show="calculate()" x-text="calculate() + '€'"></span>per session</p>
  <select x-model="data.plan">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

EDIT: to avoid calling calculate() twice each time, you can store the result inside the data object and recalculate it each time the model changes with the x-on:change attribute:

```
<div x-data="pricing()" x-init="data = {plan: 'a', priceVal: 20}">
  <p>
    <span x-text="data.priceVal + '€'" x-show="data.priceVal"></span>per
    session
  </p>
  <select x-model="data.plan" x-on:change="calculate()">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select>
</div>

export default function pricing() {
  return {
    data: {
      plan: "",
      priceVal: 20,
    },

    calculate() {
      if (this.data.plan == "a") {
        this.data.priceVal = 20;
      } else {
        this.data.priceVal = 30;
      }
    },
  };
}
```

This might be more efficient, but the 'Alpine way' would probably just be to call the function twice.

Comment: I tried that before but when the data.plan value changes the span value is not updated ... I just added all the code to my question.

Comment: Any idea why the value is not updated?

Comment: Updated my answer now since you've posted the entire code, I managed to get it working. Your x-model controlled element needs to be inside your x-data container.

Comment: I have updated my answer again to hide it. Forgot what your question was for a second. The span now correctly hides if calculate() returns null/undefined.

Comment: Calling calculate() twice is a good option? That was what I was trying to avoid

Comment: Edited the post again. Managed to come up with a solution to stop it from recalculating.

Answer (score 0):

An option can be adding a "watch" on the value:

```html
<div x-data="pricing('a')">

    <p><span x-show="calculatedPrice" x-text="calculatedPrice + '€'"></span> per session</p>

    <select x-model="data.plan">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

```js
function pricing(initialValue = null) {

    return {

        data: {
            plan: initialValue,
        },

        calculatedPrice: null,

        init() {

            this.$watch('data.plan', () => this.calculate());
            this.calculate();
        },

        calculate() {

            switch (this.data.plan)
            {
                case "a":
                    this.calculatedPrice = 20;
                    break;

                case "b":
                    this.calculatedPrice = 30;
                    break;

                default:
                    this.calculatedPrice = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I've moved the *init()* function in the *data object*, passing the initial parameter

If you want to completely hide the price row, you must move *x-show* in the <p> tag:

```html
<p x-show="calculatedPrice">
   <span x-text="calculatedPrice + '€'"></span> per session
</p>
```